# Print a number in base 4

Tags: c, printf

Lately I had a task that included printing base-4 representation of a number. Since I didn't find a function to do it for me, I implemented it (which is not so hard of course), but I wonder, is there a way to do it using format placeholders?

I'm not asking how to implement such function, but if such function / format placeholder already exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard C or C++ function, but you may be able to use [itoa](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Itoa)

Comment: +1 (when I can vote again) for pointing out itoa. stupid me, used bit-shifting...

Comment: @pmg, actually, itoa will do the job. I need to print the integer in base-4 representation, so it will give me exactly what I need. ( `itoa(myInt, buff, 4);`)

Comment: +1 Oops ... `itoa` is correct, though it's not described in the Standard: not all implementations will have it.

Comment: As far as I know, no implementations but DOS-based systems have it.

Comment: @pmg You're thinking of atoi. itoa does what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I realized that shortly after my initial comment (now deleted)

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could get to doing it with `printf` is using `snprintf` to convert it to hex, then a lookup table to convert hex digits to pairs of base-4 digits. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

No, not in the Standard C library.

Answer (score 0):

I think that printf can handle only decimal, hexadecimal and octal values.
So i think no.